# How merge two liquibase sets with different change logs?

Tags: liquibase

I want to merge sets in a complicated project.

Have two changesets defined in two different spring projects in two repositories.

Those sets keep a history of the same tables, but use different change logs and lock tables.

The second module require first in build dependency (maven) and also on code level (with Spring annotation forcing order)

I can move the whole module from the first repo to the second, but interested if there is other way to refactor it?

Tried to paste entries from the first changeset to the second, but the order is not correct and there are sql errors.